# How do I call the definition from the xslt file instead of the xml file?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

I have an HTML page with acronyms and when you hover over the acronyms it will display the definition. Essentially when you hover over an acronym, it goes out to the acronyms. Xml file to read the definition and then displays it in the tooltip.

This works between these two files – the HTML and the xml.

However, the real format of the acronyms file is an xslt file. I have removed most of its contents, but the acronyms are stored  within a  tag within the xslt. So instead of pulling the definition from the acronyms.xml we need to pull it from the acronyms.xslt.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="acronyms2.xslt"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta content="text/html;" http-equiv="Content-type"/>
    <title>Search and Seek</title>
<style>
body{
    font-family:arial;
}

.title {
    text-align: center;
}

p {
    margin-top: 0.5ex;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
}

span.def {
    color: green;
    font-style: normal;
    display: inline;
    font-weight: bold;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position:relative;
}

span.expose{
    cursor:pointer;
}

span.def.expose:before{
    content:attr(data-content);
    position:absolute;
    top:-30px;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    display:none;
    padding:4px;
    border-radius:4px;
    background:#efefef;
    color:#006eff;
    font-size:11px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    letter-spacing:1px;
}

span.def:hover:before{
    display:inline;
}

</style>
<script>
class Acronym {
  constructor() {
    this.getXHR.bind(this)(
      "GET",
      "acronyms2.xslt",
      (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
          return;
        }
        const acronyms = data.querySelectorAll("acronym");
        this.acronymMap = new Map(
          Array.from(acronyms).map((acronym) => [
            acronym.getAttribute("id"),
            acronym.textContent,
          ])
        );
        this.deploy();
      },
      true // enableDisableOutputEscaping
    );
  }

  getXHR(method, url, callback, enableDisableOutputEscaping = false) {
    console.log("getXHR", method, url);
    let x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open(method, url);

    x.onload = () => {
        console.log("onload", x.status);
      if (x.status == 404) return callback("File not found");
      let p = new DOMParser();
      let data = p.parseFromString(x.response, "application/xml");
      if (enableDisableOutputEscaping) {
        let cdata = data.documentElement.textContent;
        data = p.parseFromString(cdata, "application/xml");
      }
      callback(null, data);
    };

    x.onerror = () => {
        console.log("onerror", x.status);
      callback(x.response);
    };
    x.responseType = "document";
   
    x.send();
  }

  deploy() {
    console.log("deploy");
    let acr = document.querySelectorAll("span.def");

    for (let a of acr) {
      a.classList.add("expose");
      a.addEventListener("mouseover", this.update.bind(this, a));
    }
  }

  update(e) {
    console.log("update", e);
    let v = this.acronymMap.get(e.dataset.acronym.toUpperCase()) || "No Acronym Found";
    e.setAttribute("data-content", v);
  }
}

const a = new Acronym();
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="title">
        <h3>Test Header</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="mainbody">
        <h3> Navigating the Air </h3>
        <p>
            The <span class="def" data-acronym="ats">ATS</span> possesses tools to navigate the Air. The primary tools are <span class="def" data-acronym="afw">AFW</span> and <span class="def" data-acronym="mu">MU</span>
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

XSLT file:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
  
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Acronyms</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <acronyms>
          <acronym id="ATS">Air Traffic Services</acronym>
          <acronym id="AFW">Advanced Flexible Weather</acronym>
          <acronym id="MU">Movement Area User</acronym>
        </acronyms>
        
        <!-- rest of the XSLT file goes here -->
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- rest of the XSLT file goes here -->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML file:

```xml
<list>
    <p id="abc">All Bees Come</p>
    <p id="bdu">Bordor Down Utility</p>
    <p id="afw">Application Framework</p>
    <p id="ats">Air Traffic Service</p>
    <p id="ddb">Digital Data Bus</p>
    <p id="espg">Embedded System Processor Group</p>
    <p id="ica">International Civil Aviation</p>
    <p id="iso">In Support of</p>
    <p id="mu">Master Unit</p>
    <p id="ptm">Plain Test Message</p>
    <p id="scan">Scan Rate</p>
    <p id="tar">Tap Archive</p>
</list>
```

When I console.log the update function I get this in the console :
update <span class=​"def expose" data-acronym=​"mu" data-content=​"No Acronym Found">​MU​​

So it's being updated, but it's not pulling the definition from the xslt file for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really followed the logic of what you're doing here, but it looks like a classic use case for using SaxonJS. Normally with XSLT 1.0 in the browser, the whole thing is very static: the XSLT generates the HTML and is never seen again, it can't be used to respond to user events unless you regenerate the whole page. SaxonJS (which implements XSLT 3.0 with extensions for user interaction) allows you to control the response to user events from within the XSLT code.

Disclaimer: SaxonJS is my company's product.